# Radius of convergence of some series

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

I would like to know if I didn't make a mistake in determining the radius of convergence for the following series: (a) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n^2}}{n!}$ and (b) $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^{n^2}}{(n!)^n}$.

For (a) the ratio test yields

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{z^{(n+1)^2} n!}{(n+1)! z^{n^2}}   \right|= \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|z|^{2n+1}}{n+1}=0
$$

if and only if $|z|\leq1$. Thus the radius of convergence is one.

For (b) using the root test I have

$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{|z|^n}{n!}=0
$$

if and only if again $|z|\leq1$ and the radius of convergence is again one.

Comment: Factorial grows faster than exponential, if the base is constant, no matter what value it is

Answer (score 1):

For b) the limit as $n$ approaches infinity for the formulas is $0$ regardless of what $|z|$ is since $n!$ is in the denominator and overtakes the exponential in the numerator its growth.

I think your solution for a) is correct though since the exponential term in the top will dominate so you need that to go to $0$.